# Indentation: 4 spaces everywhere

Tags: indentation, customization

This morning, my Emacs changed its indentation rules, and now it indents by 2 spaces, specifically in JS and HTML. It even re-indents code on which I work to 2 spaces, which is unacceptable.

Please help. I need 4 spaces indentation. Please help.

What I have in my init file (none work, obviously)

```
(setq c-basic-offset 4)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)

(custom-set-variables

 '(tab-stop-list (quote (4 8 12)))
 '(tab-width 4))
```

Comment: Your JS and HTML modes most likely don’t use `c-basic-offset`. Read the manuals for the modes in question, figure out the variables they use for indentation, and make sure they’re set accordingly

Comment: As nega says, the `c-` in `c-basic-offset` indicates that it has to do with the major mode for C (and derivatives, admittedly).  `tab-width` affects the way TAB chars are displayed, and `tab-stop-list` is only used in modes which don't do automatic indentation.

Comment: "This morning, my Emacs changed its indentation rules" -- not by itself, it didn't.  Tell us what you changed or installed or updated between this morning and when it last worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(js-indent-level 4))
```

Comment: `custom-set-variables` is a special operation normally inserted and managed by Custom, so better not use it manually (you risk seeing it unexpectedly erased by Custom).  E.g. Just use `(setq js-indent-level 4)` instead.